# JMeter cannot read messages using JMS Subscriber, giving me 404 status code as a response

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, message-queue, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to read messages from ActiveMQ Artemis using JMeter. For that I use JMS Subscriber. For some reason I can't read messages, it gives me an 404 response code. I think that I'm making everything correct, but it doesn't works. Here is what have I done.

[image]

and here is the response.

[image]

my ActiveMQ looks like that: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in Destination field. I should have use dynamicQueues/GDE.Error instead of dynamicTopics/GDE.Error .